# Detect the language of the browser in selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

I'm trying to detect the language & culture of the browser, i need it so could format the date string to input it to the date field. 
I'm using Chrome as browser, selenium python and Pycharm as IDE.

[image: Here screen capture of the date field formats]

Comment: is there a pattern attribute in the underlying HTML? something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A javascript solution for getting the browsers language:

```
var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
console.log(lang); //example output: 'en-GB'
```

You could then use the language in combination with toLocalDateString() to get the correct date format, for example:

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(date.toLocaleDateString(lang));
```

You can execute javascript in selenium like so:

```
language = driver.execute_script("return window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language")
```

I hope this helps.